# Querying arrays stored as comma separated strings in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have to search on many associated models through a has_many relationship. For argument's sake, let's say I have a Product model with many categories through a has_many association. Because I have to do this with many of the parent model's child associations, I've created a cache table, where I store all the id's in the association as a comma separated string - '23,34,56,78' rather than doing a join. This also helps with advanced searches I need to do later with conditional ANDs on the category ids.

My question is what is the best way to query the presence of an id in such a string in active record. If for example, I want all parent models with associations of ids 34, 56 and 78.

To accurately search on one id I have to search for '%,34,%', '34,%', '%,34' to account for different positions in the string an id can occupy. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Its that really faster than doing a join?  That seems like an odd approach.

Comment: Hah, good question. Part of the problem is that I'm building a search system along the lines of http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised so another plus of this system is simplifying the queries involving has_many with AND. Does that make sense yet?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the search aspect of this will ultimately need to look at 6-8 has_many relationships. So I thought a cache table might simplify things.

Comment: There is a very handy gem you might want to look at: https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope.  It greatly simplifies queries based on request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how fast this would be but you can split the string by commas to create an array then do a `.includes?()` on said array... But is this really any faster than SQL?

```
value.split(',').includes?(other_value)
```

or with multiple items:

```
value.split(',') && [id1, id2, id3]
```

This will return a list of ids that appear in both arrays.